# How to access a property whose name consists of an asterisk in PowerShell?

Tags: json, powershell, wikipedia-api

The wikipedia API returns JSON that contains an element with the name `*`. How can I access such a property in PowerShell?

Example:

```bsh
$json = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&pageid=10000&prop=wikitext&format=json'
$json.parse.wikitext.* # fails
```

Error: "Missing property name after reference operator." So the asterisk is not recognized as a property name.

JSON excerpt:

```
{ 
   "parse": { 
      "title": "Eiffel",
      "pageid": 10000,
      "wikitext": { 
         "*": "{{Wiktionary|Eiffel}}\n'''Eiffel''' ..."
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `$json.parse.wikitext."*"` would do. PowerShell is well-equipped to handle all manner of crazy member names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it in quotation marks:

```
$json.parse.wikitext."*"
```

Comment: If I may give my two cents in the matter, when dealing with text that may be interpreted as a special character, use single quotation marks, that way PowerShell will read the string literally.

Comment: @OrelFichman That doesn't make any difference here.  What you're referring to are escape characters and string interpolation.  Single quotes represent string literals.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley True, but Orel's advice makes sense _as a good general habit to form_: if you know that something is a _literal_ (verbatim) string, use `'...'`; if you need _string expansion_, i.e. interpolation of escape sequences, variable references and expressions embedded in a string, use `"..."`. From that perspective, given that the `*` is to be used _verbatim_, `$json.parse.wikitext.'*'` as the solution is preferable here.